# Docker Compose Not Allowing External Library Debugging

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, sourcelink

I'm trying to debug an inhouse library while running my application in a container using **docker-compose.**

I've setup the internal library with the following settings as per the SourceLink documentation [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink). I am publishing the NUGET package to **Azure Devops Artifact**.

I can debug the external library when running the project and I can see .pdb files are loaded in the Debugging **Modules** window. The symbol file is also in the correct **symbolCache** location

`C:\Users\darrent\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\LAWFORALL.Seedwork.pdb\3ca3000ecd7b49ae82c712ab8757040effffffff\LAWFORALL.Seedwork.pdb`

When running the same project using docker-compose I cannot step into the library and symbols aren't loaded.

Below is an extract on my package using **Nuget Package Explorer**
[image: Nuget Package]

Below is the configuration that resides in the `.csproj` file of my package.

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
        <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
        <ContinuousIntegrationBuild>true</ContinuousIntegrationBuild>
        <PublishSymbols>true</PublishSymbols>
        
        <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
        <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
        <SymbolPackageFormat>symbols.nupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

My debugging settings in the project are as follows.
[image]

I've added the Azure Devops as a Symbol location as per the image below.
[image]

Comment: I've been having this issue as well. One day while searching on GitHub, I found an issue that detailed this as something known and not working. However, in going back to look for it, I can't find the ticket on GitHub. Have you made any progress on this?